# General term of a non linear recurrence relation

Tags: recurrence-relations, exact-sequence

I have a problem today where I think I Iack of theory for solving it and hence I came here to ask for your help. The problem is the following :

> find the general term of the sequence $$ x_{n+1} = x_n^2 + 1$$ where $x_0 = 3$.

I know how to solve for linear recurrence relations but I'm a bit lost here. I thank you in advance for the answers you shall give me.

Comment: There is no closed form that can be found using Wolfram so I doubt a simple closed form exists. Each term is roughly equal to $10^{2^{n-1}}$.

Comment: Have a look at http://oeis.org/search?q=3%2C+10%2C+101%2C+10202%2C+104080805&sort=&language=&go=Search

Answer (score 1):

The [OEIS sequence A062013](https://oeis.org/A062013) is given by $\, a_1 = 3,\quad a_n = a_{n-1}^2+1.\,$ This sequence has a power series formula ($B(x)$ as appears in [OEIS sequence A088674](https://oeis.org/A088674)) given by
$$ a_n = B(x) = \frac1{2x} - x - 3 x^3 - 6 x^5 - 45 x^7 - \dots\; \text{ where }
 x = \frac1{2c^{2^n}}, \; c \approx 1.7805035.$$